# I have the Android SDK Downloaded, and a AVD created. How can I get apps for it?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I can't seem to find any options to retrieve apps on my SDK's virtual Android device. Can you direct me to where I may find apps so that I can test them out?

Answer (score 0):

AndAppStore (www.andappstore.com)